# Cakephp3.8-Displayed the more pages when i have no Record

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I am using the Cakephp3.8 paginate function for displaying the records. when I have records its working normally.
when I don't have any records it's still displayed the paginate Numbers. How can I remove?

```
    $paginate = [
        'limit' => 8,
         'page' => 1,
 =>        'order' => [
            'Articles.title' => 'asc'
        ]
    ];
```

[image]

Comment: try to debug it by printing these variable $get_total_rows, $total_pages or post whole controller, model and view parts

Answer (score 1):

You can check in your View if your ResultSet contains items and display your pagination depending on that:

Add the if statement to check if articles is not empty:

```
<?php if (!$articles->isEmpty()): ?>
  <div class="paginator">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <?= $this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('First')) ?>
      <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('Previous')) ?>
      <?= $this->Paginator->numbers(['before' => '', 'after' => '']) ?>
      <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('Next') . ' >') ?>
      <?= $this->Paginator->last(__('Last') . ' >>') ?>
    </ul>
    <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter(__('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total')) ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

More on Control Structures for [Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html#alternative-control-structures).